# captionof increases count by 2

Tags: captions, minipage

I face a similiar problem like the one described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31042/table-counter-increasing-by-2-for-every-table). I created a command that will output a caption besides an image (in this example replaced by simple text).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{vwcol}  
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{format=plain,width=0.7\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\yasfig}[3]
{\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.3,0.7},
 sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=0em]
#1

\begin{minipage}{0.68\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{#2}
\label{#3}
\end{minipage}
\end{vwcol}}

\yasfig{Gel}{Bla}{fig:Gel}
\yasfig{Blot}{Bla}{fig:Blot}

\end{document}
```

This will output the desired layout but increase the figure count by 2 each time the command is called. I'm guessing it has something to do with the minipage but I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is to place the caption beside the image, then there are other ways than using a multi-column environment, such as using two `minipage`s next to one another, the first with the image, the second with the caption. Another way is to use the `captionofbeside` environment provided by the KOMA classes.

Note that I don't know exactly how wide you wanted the images and caption, so you may want to modify the widths. The `minipage` in the `captionofbeside` environment isn't strictly necessary. Some modifications may also be necessary with regard to the vertical alignment of caption and image, but I don't know exactly how you want that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{format=plain,width=0.7\textwidth}

\newcommand{\yasfig}[3]
{\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
#1
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.68\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{#2}
\label{#3}
\end{minipage}}

\newcommand\yyasfig[3]{%
\noindent\begin{captionofbeside}{figure}{#2\label{#3}}[r]
\begin{minipage}{.25\linewidth}
#1
\end{minipage}
\end{captionofbeside}}
\begin{document}

\yasfig{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}{Bla}{fig:Gel}
\yasfig{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}{Bla}{fig:Blot}

\yyasfig{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}{Bla}{fig:Gel2}
\yyasfig{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-c}}{Bla}{fig:Blot2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it fixes it, but I subtract 1 from the figure counter before leaving `vwcol`, and then add it back in after leaving the environment.  Something to do with `vwcol`, I presume, or else as you suspect, and interaction of `vwcol` and `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{vwcol}  
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{format=plain,width=0.7\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\yasfig}[3]
{\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.3,0.7},
 sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=0em]
#1

\begin{minipage}{0.68\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{#2}
\label{#3}
\end{minipage}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\end{vwcol}\addtocounter{figure}{1}%
}

\yasfig{Gel}{Bla}{fig:Gel}
\yasfig{Blot}{Bla}{fig:Blot}

\end{document}
```

[image]