# caption with ltablex and ThreePartTable - the caption is increased by 2

Tags: tables, floats, captions, ltablex, threeparttablex

I'm using `threeparttablex` and `tabularx` packages.

I have 2 problems:

1. caption only enumerates right if put before `\begin{tabularx}`;
2. notes are not center aligned with the table;

[image]

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,ltablex,threeparttablex}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{LL}
    \toprule
    ex1 & ex2\\
    ex3 & ex4\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
            \item[a] note1.
            \item[b] note2.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \caption{Example.}\label{tab:dummy}%
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've tried many approaches: using `tabularx` with `threeparttable` instead, with `captionof{table}{caption}` and the problem is the same: if I put it before `tabularx` env. it works, else the caption number increments by two (so I have Table 2.2, 2.4, 2.6 and so on... ); if I use `tabular` instead, it works fine both ways. I don't get it....

What am I doing wrong? I really have to use `tabularx` though...

Comment: What is the `L`specifier?

Comment: I've added some code from your previous question to show the problem. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: To center the notes, simply add `\centering` inside `tablenotes`.  Why do you need `tabularx`?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Actually, `ltablex` loads `tabularx`(and perhaps patches it, didn't check).)

Comment: You can clearly see that `ltablex` makes the `tabularx` environment do wrong.

Comment: ThreePartTable does not do you any good here, it is for longtable. Use threeparttable when it is a single page table. Also I'd leave the caption outside the threeparttable

Comment: Crosslink: related question, [numbering - Table counter increasing by 2 for every table - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31042/table-counter-increasing-by-2-for-every-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unorthodox solution: put the caption *inside* the tabularx environment (as would be done for `longtable`).
Some comments about your code: with `threeparttablex`, the `tablenotes` is replaced with  `TableNotes` is *declared* at the very beginning, and is inserted later wheare you please with the `\insertTableNotes` commands. Also, if you really want to have a table with true `X` columns, you have to use the `\keepXColumns` command; else the calculated X width  is only the maximum width of columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, ltablex}%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

\section{A First Section}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[a] note1.
\item[b] note2.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{X}}%
\toprule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
ex1 & ex2\\
ex3 & ex4\\
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes\\
\caption{Example1.}\label{tab:dummy}
\end{tabularx}%%
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
\item[a] note1.
\item[b] note2.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{X}}%
\caption{Example 2.}\label{tab:dummy}\\
\toprule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
ex1 & ex2\\
ex3 & ex4\\
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes\\
\end{tabularx}%%
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in My comment above, ThreePartTable and TableNotes are intended with longtable. Does not make much sense with other constructions

Comment: I've used ThreePartTable with tabularx via ltablex, because most of the times I have really big tables that cross pages, which is not this case in particular. I will try your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @Bernard your example 1 works just fine for me. I always use tabularx. I just loaded the ltablex (which requires tabularx,right?) because of the long tables I've added before (with 1endhead, \endfoot an so...).

Comment: @neverMind: I didn't test an example of a tabularx environment that breaks across pages, so I'm not sure it works in  such a case.

Comment: I have an example of tabularx with huge tables spanning across several pages, but `without* tablenotes and they're fine. The only difference is that I've defined `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, etc accordingly to my needs. With bigtables *and* ThreePartTable I haven't tried...yet. I hope that ThreePartTable doesn't ruin the table :P

Comment: In any case you can convert it to longtable with suitable `p{some width}`.

Comment: @Bernard, tabularx via ltablex = longtable for tabularx, so I don't need it. In fact, I've tried it and it didn't go as well as I expcted. So, for now, tabularx meets all my needs: short tables with table notes and longtables with tabular with X columns (or variations of it: L, R...)

Comment: Yes, but if threeparttablex doesn't work with tabularx that break across pages? That's what I meant.

Comment: Sadly the table notes are restricted to the length of one column in that case. Which makes them look pretty bad, when you have quite a few columns.

Comment: @SarahMultitasker: Stange. Did you try `\multicolumn{…}{\InsertTableNotes}`?

Comment: @Bernard Doesn't compile. "Misplaced \noalign". Entered \multicolumn{4}{l}{\insertTableNotes} since I have 4 columns.

Comment: @SarahMultitasker: In this case, I'll try to see what can be done.