# Tabularx is increasing the table numeration even without \caption

Tags: numbering, tabularx, threeparttable, ltablex, threeparttablex

I'm using `ltablex` and `threeparttablex` for my long tables across 2 or 3 pages. However, into the text body I use `tabularx` without the intention of numbering, but the `tabularx` environment is increasing the numeration of the tables. Any help?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,ltablex,threeparttablex,blindtext}


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2\\
Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2
\end{tabularx}

\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc}
\caption{Example}
\label{tab:dummy}\\
\toprule
ex1 & ex2\\
ex3 & ex4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[a] note1.
\item[b] note2.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabularx` tries to determine the column widths etc. (you're not using `X` columns at all, so why using `tabularx` here?) and as such is evaluating the code at least twice, i.e. the `\caption` is called twice at least and increases the table counter. By the way, `\caption` inside the `tabularx` environment is weird

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm using the ´tabularx´ for the `X` columns. In this MWE I want to focus in the numbering problem. The `caption` inside the `tabularx` is recommended for the type os tables that I'm using

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: `caption` inside  `tabularx` is not so weird with package `ltablex`:  for tabularxs that break across pages, one has to use the `longtable` syntax.

Comment: @Bernard: I missed the `ltablex` stuff issue, in this `\caption` is alright there

Comment: by the way also longtable increases table counter even when the longtable has no caption

Comment: Crosslink: related question, [numbering - Table counter increasing by 2 for every table - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31042/table-counter-increasing-by-2-for-every-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix with a new environment that reduces the counter (increased by tabularx environment through "ltablex" package)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs,threeparttablex,blindtext,environ}

\NewEnviron{mytabularx}[2]{\begin{tabularx}{#1}{#2}\BODY\end{tabularx}\addtocounter{table}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{mytabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2\\
Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2
\end{mytabularx}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Example}\label{tab:dummy}
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{mytabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
\toprule
ex1 & ex2\\
ex3 & ex4\\
\bottomrule
\end{mytabularx}%
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[a] note1.
\item[b] note2.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}

\begin{mytabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2\\
Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2
\end{mytabularx}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Example}\label{tab:dummy2}
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{mytabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
\toprule
ex1 & ex2\\
ex3 & ex4\\
\bottomrule
\end{mytabularx}%
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[a] note1.
\item[b] note2.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]