# Why "shellesc" conflicts with "tabularx" and how to fix?

Tags: tabularx, shell-escape

This is the code that works just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    hello!
    &
    \ShellEscape{/bin/echo 'hello!' > a.tex}
    \input{a}
    \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, if I use `tabularx` instead of `tabular`, compilation stops at the `\input`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lr}
    hello!
    &
    \ShellEscape{/bin/echo 'hello!' > a.tex}
    \input{a}
    \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Quick note: Essentially same issue as [numbering - Table counter increasing by 2 for every table - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31042/table-counter-increasing-by-2-for-every-table) . tabularx runs the code inside some (all?) cell twice.

Comment: tabularx evaluates it's body multiple times, writing is disabled during trials as for example you don't want \label to be written multiple times. so the write will only happen on the last run, so the file a.tex is not available when you input it during trials

Comment: Actually it isn't everything, but if the parent file happen to be also named `a.tex` (which is what happens in my testing) then it is part of the issue.

Comment: @user202729 well yes obviously if you have a file a.tex that inputs a.tex you loop, but here in general it isn't clear what the code should do, you can avoid the error by not doing the input or shellescape during trial runs, but then the trials are all invalid as they are not using text used for the final run

Comment: Obviously the most efficient (in terms of CPU time) method would be to move the shell-escape outside the tabular (note that anything stateful will fail anyway because things are evaluated twice), but forcing the shell escape to execute twice would also give correct (compared to `tabular`) printed output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705849/why-shellesc-conflicts-with-tabularx-and-how-to-fix#comment1754813_705849) you can test if the file exists and only input it in that case. Then the table cell will be filled in the last run.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lr}
    hello!
    &
    \ShellEscape{/bin/echo 'hello!' > a.tex}
    \IfFileExists{./a.tex}{\input{a}}{}
    \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```